# What's the technical of conjoining two words into one word?

Tags: word-request

What's the technical of conjoining two words into one word? For example, taking the words "bath" and "water" to create the word "bathwater". What is the technical word for this? I am thinking there must be a word for this since in the English language we do it very often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Words made up of two or more words joined together are called compounds, e.g. compound nouns, and the process by which they are formed is called **compounding** by linguists.

> In this paper we discuss noun compounding, a highly generative,
>   productive process, in three distinct languages: Czech, English and.
>   Zulu.

[Noun Compounds in Czech, English and Zulu](http://www.lrec-conf.org/proceedings/lrec2010/pdf/883_Paper.pdf)